# Stepper component in latest Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use Material UI horizontal steppers. But I am not able to add content to it. Hence, I thought I'll switch to Bootstrap. I've gone through the documentation and examples but did not find any implementation for Stepper. Is there any other package I can use for this? Or is there a way to implement content with Material UI horizontal stepper to achieve the purpose?

This is my current implementation, but it's just not right!

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Stepper from '@mui/material/Stepper';
import Step from '@mui/material/Step';
import StepLabel from '@mui/material/StepLabel';
import StepContent from '@mui/material/StepContent';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import FirstStep from './FirstStep';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';

const steps = [1, 2, 3];



function getStepContent(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <>
        <Grid align="center">
        <form class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name"></input>
        <br></br>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"></input>
        </form>
        </Grid>
           
        </>
     
      );
    case 1:
      return (
        <form class="form-group">
        <label>High School Percentage</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="High School Percentage"></input>
        <br></br>
        <label>Graduation percentage</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Graduation Percentage"></input>
        </form>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <form class="form-group">
        <label>Permanent Address</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Permanent Address"></input>
        <br></br>
        <label>Temporary Address</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Temporary Address"></input>
        </form>
      );
    default:
      return '';
  }
}

export default function EdenSignUp() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());

  const isStepOptional = (step) => {
    return step === 1;
  };

  const isStepSkipped = (step) => {
    return skipped.has(step);
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    let newSkipped = skipped;
    if (isStepSkipped(activeStep)) {
      newSkipped = new Set(newSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.delete(activeStep);
    }

    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped(newSkipped);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleSkip = () => {
    if (!isStepOptional(activeStep)) {
      // You probably want to guard against something like this,
      // it should never occur unless someone's actively trying to break something.
      throw new Error("You can't skip a step that isn't optional.");
    }

    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped((prevSkipped) => {
      const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.add(activeStep);
      return newSkipped;
    });
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel='true' >
        {steps.map((label, index) => {
          const stepProps = {};
          const labelProps = {};
          if (isStepOptional(index)) {
            labelProps.optional = (
              <Typography variant="caption"></Typography>
            );
          }
          if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
            stepProps.completed = false;
          }
          return (
            <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
              <StepLabel {...labelProps}> 
            
              {label}</StepLabel>
              {/* <Typography>
              {getStepContent(label)}
              </Typography> */}

<StepContent orientation = 'horizontal'>
              <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
              <div >
                <div>
                  <Button
                    disabled={activeStep === 0}
                    onClick={handleBack}
                    // className={classes.button}
                  >
                    Back
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    // className={classes.button}
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </StepContent>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
       
             
        
        
      </Stepper>
       {activeStep === steps.length ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          {/* <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>
            All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
          </Typography> */}
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', pt: 2 }}>
            <Box sx={{ flex: '1 1 auto' }} />
         
           
            <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
            
           
          </Box>
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>Step {activeStep + 1}</Typography>
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', pt: 2 }}>
            <Button
              color="inherit"
              disabled={activeStep === 0}
              onClick={handleBack}
              sx={{ mr: 1 }}
            >
              Back
            </Button>
            <Box sx={{ flex: '1 1 auto' }} />
            {isStepOptional(activeStep) && (
              <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleSkip} sx={{ mr: 1 }}>
                Skip
              </Button>
            )}

            <Button onClick={handleNext}>
              {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </React.Fragment>
      )} 
      
        
      
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react-stepper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form-stepper) also, See in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sapient-test-forked-63lplp?file=/App.js)

Comment: you could have added more description in your answer instead of just links... links can be unavailable in the future...

Comment: you could have added more description in your answer instead of just links... links can be unavailable in the future...